# Error al cargar Datos en Paginación Gridview

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, gridview, paginación

Al clickear en *siguiente* de mi paginación del Gridview no carga los Datos correspondientes, sino que tengo que precionar nuevamente el Botón de Búsqueda para que cargue los datos de esa página.

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto?

El Siguiente Código lo Ocupo Para Llenar un Gridview:

```
 protected void Btnbuscar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),fecha_captura, 121) AS DIA, ctl.tipo AS TIPO, COUNT(lic.tipo_licencia_id ) as TOTAL FROM LICENCIAS lic join CAT_TIPO_LICENCIAS ctl on lic.tipo_licencia_id = ctl.tipo_licencia_id where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fecha_captura, 121) BETWEEN '" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND '" + TextBox2.Text + "' GROUP BY ctl.tipo, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fecha_captura, 121)  order by DIA desc, tipo asc; ", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

y en mi Vista:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server" placeholder="Filtrar"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server" placeholder="Filtrar"></asp:TextBox>
               <%-- <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">--%>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <div align="right"><asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" onclick="Btnbuscar" Text="Buscar"/> </div>                        
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="15" Width="280px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
                      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                      <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
                      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                      <PagerSettings FirstPageText="Primera" LastPageText="última" NextPageText="Siguiente" PreviousPageText="Anterior" PageButtonCount="15" />

                      <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                      <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
                      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
                      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
                      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
                      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />

                  </asp:GridView>
```

No tengo ningún problema al cargar mi página me trae los Datos al igual que filtrar por fechas con mis 2 Textbox, el punto es que al Dar a la página siguiente en mi Gridview no me refresca esos datos sino hasta que doy clic al Evento del Botón.

Comment: Por favor [edit] la pregunta y coloca el código que tengas en el método `Page_Load`.

Comment: @Muricio Hola, te comento que al evento Load de la Page no le tengo nada cargado.......unicamente al evento del botón le Cargo Los Datos. Saludos. Bueno y mi conexion que esta definida en mi clase. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera:

- El código que tienes en el botón, colócalo en una nuevo método.
- En el evento `Page_Load` coloca el llamado al nuevo método.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
/// Page_Load.
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Llama al método.
        CargarDatos();
    }
}

// En este método tienes la lógica.
protected void CargarDatos()
{
    try
    {

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),fecha_captura, 121) AS DIA, ctl.tipo AS TIPO, COUNT(lic.tipo_licencia_id ) as TOTAL FROM LICENCIAS lic join CAT_TIPO_LICENCIAS ctl on lic.tipo_licencia_id = ctl.tipo_licencia_id where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fecha_captura, 121) BETWEEN '" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND '" + TextBox2.Text + "' GROUP BY ctl.tipo, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fecha_captura, 121)  order by DIA desc, tipo asc; ", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

// Al presionar el botón, llama al método.
protected void Btnbuscar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CargarDatos();
}

  protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        CargarDatos();
    }
```

Comment: Genial Bro. Ayer me Ayudaste y hoy Abriste la Pauta, para la solución. Se Agrega la parte del Paginado, allí se debe hacer referencia al Metodo  CargarDatos(); Esa era mi falla la lógica tuya Abrió la Pauta. Gracias a alguien mas servirá. Saludos. Por ahí deberías Abrir tus Cursos :)

Comment: @Abraham, si mi respuesta resolvió tu problema, por favor, [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.